# How to loop through a JSON array using for each in Zoho CRM Deluge script

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, zoho, zoho-deluge

**im a bit confused on how to declare an array in a deluge script. I have seen the references online but somehow i may not be using this syntax right:

> x = List();

**
and here is my foreach loop
[image]

**request_body** is receiving the JSON array from my server

I get an error ***Argument type mismatches for the integration function 'zoho.crm.createrecord' at index 2 Line Number: 15***

this my code to send the JSON array to CRM

```js
async function sendToCRM(pets) {
    var jsonPets = JSON.stringify(pets)

    superagent
    .post(insertPet_URL)
    .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .send(jsonPets)
    .end((e, r) => {
      console.log(r.body)
    })// sends a JSON post body
  }

  app.post("/pets", (req,res)=> {
    var pets = req.body
    var petsData = []

    pets.forEach(function(pet){
      var tmp = {}

      tmp["Name"] = pet.Ngalan
      tmp["Pet_Owner"] = pet.Tagiya
      tmp["Contact_Number"] = pet.Numero
      tmp["Birthdate"] = pet.Kaadlawan
      tmp["Breed"] = pet.Rasa

      petsData.push(tmp)
    })
    console.log(petsData)
    sendToCRM(petsData)
    res.send(req.body)
    res.status(200)
  })
```

there has been no problem on the server side and im able to receive this JSON array from Postman which is the one im going to send to CRM deluge. Here is my JSON array:

```
[{"Ngalan":"Hachi","Tagiya":"Rex","Numero":"09778135353","Kaadlawan":"2020-12-12","Rasa":"Akita Inu"},{"Ngalan":"qwe","Tagiya":"Rex","Numero":"09778135353","Kaadlawan":"2020-12-12","Rasa":"Akita Inu"}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/crm/create-record.html#Syntax The `record_details` should be of type key-value, you are probably passing only values.

Comment: Thanks! but since my JSON is an array of objects, any idea how to loop them using foreach? I haven't found any resources online regarding this.

Comment: You should use a `Map` instead of `List` for `x`. And store key-value pairs inside it. Something like `x = map()`, `x.put("PetName", request_body.get("Pet_Name"))`

Comment: Thanks so much! I did what you told me but I got an _error_ on my server side **Argument type mismatch - Found 'TEXT' but Expected '[BIGINT]' for the function 'get'**. I also changed the `pet_data = List();` to `pet_data = Map();` since i also get the same _error_ on CRM

Comment: Basically, `x` should be a key-value type. Not sure what is the appropriate type for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the request_body.tojsonlist(). then it work

Answer (score 0):

First extract the keys from your response object, then iterate through your list and get the values

```
keys = request_body.keys();
for each key in keys
    {
         value = request_body.get(key)
    }
```